# How do you update a cached resource in an angular service?

Tags: angularjs, caching, angularjs-service, angularjs-resource

## What is a good pattern for updating angular data from a ngResource service that has been cached?

I been trawling posts like this one [1]: [How to refresh / invalidate $resource cache in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059569/how-to-refresh-invalidate-resource-cache-in-angularjs), but would be good to hear from angular experts on the right approach for this specific (but pretty general) scenario.

I am looking for a general pattern here. Both in understanding and in implementing angular - I am a novice at it.

I have a pretty standard `ngResource` service that has a very standard `query` method, and a custom put method `update`.

```
myServices.factory('ThingsService', [
'$resource',
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/things/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true, cache: true },
        update: {method: 'PUT', cache: true },
    });
}]);
```

I am using it from a controller like this:

```
    $scope.things = ThingsService.query(function (x) {
        // must assign these only once data is loaded
        $scope.allCount = x.Things.length;
        $scope.incomingCount = $filter('filter')(x.Things, { State: 'incoming' }).length;
    });
```

So far so good. The data is returned just fine, and it renders nicely in a dashboard view. 
We support in-place-editing and the user can edit the data right there in the dashboard list. 
First take a shadow copy of the `thing` using `angular.copy(...)` so that we can support buffering of the changes for the user. (just like a dialog box does for a user). Then when they confirm their changes, we call with the shadow copy:

```
        ThingsService.update({ id: currentThing.Id }, { Data: currentThing.Data }, function () {
            //TODO: now, if this PUT succeeds, 
            //I want to update the value of $scope.things array to reflect the changes, 
            //without going to back to the server for the whole array.
        });
```

This correctly PUTS the changes to the server, which returns an updated `thing`, but the dashboard view which is bound to the `query` method is not updated auto-magically. Was kind of hoping angular and the `ThingsService` and its cache would take care of that for me somehow, you know by updating the cached data. Since the service should know that I just updated one of the items that the service serves up.

So to avoid going all the way back to the server we have told the `ThingsService` to cache its results, which is a good start. But how are you supposed to update the changed `thing` in the cached data?

Is there a standard pattern for this kind of update with a `ngResource` service?

Preferably I wouldn't have to mess with the cache directly. I should not even care that it is cached or how. I just want `$scope.things` to reflect the posted changes changes.