# clear cache of angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

In my use case I have  Carts and LineItems. My REST service has the following resource urls:

```
get|post|delete|put api/v1/carts/:cartId

get|post|delete|put api/v1/carts/:cartId/lineItems/:lineItemId

get|post|delete|put api/v1/lineItems/:lineItemId
```

the probelm is that when I do:

```
delete api/v1/carts/Default/lineItem/:lineItemId
```

and then I do:

```
get api/v1/carts/Default
```

angular does not hit the server to get the cart, but it gets it from cache which returns the deleted line item back in the cart
I tried all sorts of trick, tried disabling the cache by adding the {cache: false} option, but could not get it to work
the only way I was able to get it to work was if I make a POST request to

```
api/v1/carts/Default
```

with an empty body, which tells angular that the resource has changed and clears the cache.
Even though it works it seams like a hacky solution, so I was wandering if someone might have a suggestion of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059569/how-to-refresh-invalidate-resource-cache-in-angularjs

Answer (score 3):

Get requests are cached by browsers. Simplest way is to use timestamp:
instead of GET /user/100 use GET /user/100?time=120229393
With such request you will always hit server.

If you need this in multiple requests, you can make http interceptor to add timestamp param to request.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Petr