# Angularjs $http cache refresh

Tags: angularjs, http, caching

I need to to refresh the cache after i add new data to database.

```
angular.module('app').factory('myService', function ($http,$cacheFactory) {

  var profileCache=$cacheFactory('profiles');

  //get list of items
  function getItem(){
   var request=$http({
     method:'get',
     url:domain+'/api/v1/items/list',
     cache:profileCache,
     params:{
       action:'get'
     }
   });
   return(request.then(response.data));
 }
// Post items
 function addItem(item){
   var request=$http({
     method:'post',
     url:domain+'/api/v1/items/add',
     data:item
   });
   return(request.then(response.data));
 }
})
```

I want to refresh the cache once the item is added,so that the cache can have new changed data.

Comment: This might be helpful to you [Refresh or invalidate the cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059569/how-to-refresh-invalidate-resource-cache-in-angularjs)

Comment: @GitaramKanawade Yup saw it. Buy could not implement it as wished.

Answer (score 0):

as you can read here

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

**$http responses are not cached by default**

but if you have particular environment and you need to prevent any caching you can add a date time to your request
example

```
function getItem(){
   var d = new Date();
   var n = d.getDate();
   var request=$http({
     method:'get',
     url:domain+'/api/v1/items/list?' + n,
     cache:true,
     params:{
       action:'get'
     }
   });
   return(request.then(response.data));
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

var $httpDefaultCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');

Comment: The answer does not make any sense. Please add some description.

Comment: I suggest to add some explanation - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer